# How to assign different http proxy for different svn repo's in intelliji IDEA?

Tags: svn, proxy, intellij-idea

I work behind multi-proxy network. I need use different proxy for different SVN repos.

How to assign different http proxy for different svn URL's in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDEA uses your system Subversion configuration file where you can specify proxy for repositories. If your command line SVN works fine, then IDEA integration should work fine as well.

Note that current IDEA versions may use non-default Subversion configuration directory in your user profile (~/.subversion_IDEA on Linux/Mac), so you may need to copy your original config there or set up IDEA to use the explicit Subversion configuration directory.